# Java performance multi-core testing environment

Tags: java, performance

I am interested in learning as much as i can about tuning a multi-threaded java server on a multi-core machine.   I wanted to write some test servers that i could use to test different scenarios.  For example thread pool sizing.  Unfortunately i don't have access to a large multi-core unix (linux or solaris) machine.  I just have duo-core mac laptop.

Are there any good lease options for a dedicated, say 8 to 16 core machine, that i could distribute my java test servers?

Comment: Do you have a specific question here? This sounds quite vague and open-ended to me. Probably the best thing to do is find a good book on the topic.

Comment: Sorry i'm asking if any one knows of a machine leasing option that would allow me to test java in a multi-core environment.

Comment: This is not a programming question but a hardware purchase lease question appropriate to super-user or probably better server-fault. Should move to more appropriate forum.

Comment: Apologies for the mis-use.  I'll post on super-user.  thanks

Comment: Since an answer has been awarded see if you can get it moved. (Flag the question for moderator attention)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get an Amazon EC2 **Quadruple Extra Large** (u$d 1.60 per hour). It is a dual quad core computer, and each core can run 2 threads, so you get a total of 16 threads.

You can get more information here
http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/
http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/hpc-applications/